Proof of an approximation of $\pi$
Here is an approximation of $\pi$:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Proof
$$\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1} = \frac{4(1^2)}{4(1^2)-1}*\frac{4(2^2)}{4(2^2)-1}*\frac{4(3^2)}{4(3^2)-1}*...$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}*\frac{16}{15}*\frac{36}{35}*...$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}*\frac{4}{3}*\frac{4}{5}*\frac{6}{5}*\frac{6}{7}*\frac{8}{7}*...$$
$$=\frac{4}{1}*\frac{6}{5}*\frac{8}{7}*...$$
$$=\frac{4}{5}*\frac{6}{7}*\frac{8}{9}*...$$
Now, we recognize this as the Wallis Product, which converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$
The Wallis Product is defined as:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{2}{1}*\frac{2}{3}*\frac{4}{3}*\frac{4}{5}*\frac{6}{5}*\frac{6}{7}*\frac{8}{7}*\frac{8}{9}*...$$
Comparing this to the manipulated product we derived earlier, we can see that they are equivalent.
Therefore, we have proved that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Is this correct?

The idea is good however the formalism has not proven anything, use explicitly $4k^2-1 = (2k+1)(2k-1)$, and do it on the finite products then pass to the limit

You cannot say $\frac{4}{1}\times\frac{6}{5}\times\frac{8}{7}\times \cdots=\frac{4}{5}\times\frac{6}{7}\times \frac{8}{9}\times \cdots$ as the LHS clearly exceeds $1$ and the RHS is clearly less than $1$.

On the other hand $\frac{4}{3}\times\frac{16}{15}\times\frac{36}{35}\times \cdots$ is the paired Wallis product $\left(\frac{2}{1}\times\frac{2}{3} \right)\times\left(\frac{4}{3}\times\frac{4}{5} \right)\times\left(\frac{6}{5}\times\frac{6}{7} \right)\times \cdots$ justified using partital products
